# NotFoundError: Key not found in database [hn]

Tags: solidity, remix, error, solidity-0.6.x, safemath

I'm playing Ethernaut (https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/).

I'm currently on level 3 (Coin Flip).

This is the Coin Flip contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import '@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol';

contract CoinFlip {

  using SafeMath for uint256;
  uint256 public consecutiveWins;
  uint256 lastHash;
  uint256 FACTOR = 57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968;

  constructor() public {
    consecutiveWins = 0;
  }

  function flip(bool _guess) public returns (bool) {
    uint256 blockValue = uint256(blockhash(block.number.sub(1)));

    if (lastHash == blockValue) {
      revert();
    }

    lastHash = blockValue;
    uint256 coinFlip = blockValue.div(FACTOR);
    bool side = coinFlip == 1 ? true : false;

    if (side == _guess) {
      consecutiveWins++;
      return true;
    } else {
      consecutiveWins = 0;
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I deployed this code in the Remix IDE.

However, whenever I call `flip()`, I get:

`transact to CoinFlip.flip errored: NotFoundError: Key not found in database [hn]`

I searched for this problem online, but most related questions involve Web3, Ganache, RPCs or something of the sort. And the answers aren't really what I'm looking for.

I tried:

- `flip()`
- `flip(0)`
- `flip(1)`
- `flip(false)`
- `flip(true)`
- `flip("false")`
- `flip("true")`
- increasing the gasLimit
- refreshing the page

Nothing fixed it. Same error gets thrown.

Am I doing something wrong? Is the problem in the Smart Contract? Or is it in Remix?

**Secondary Question:** What's the proper way to pass in a bool parameter to a function?

0 and 1? false and true? "false" and "true"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same error when solving the same Ethernaut level. I'm using Remix IDE. When I changed from deploying with `JavaScript VM` to deploying with `Injected Web3` (there's a dropdown menu in DEPLOY & RUN TRANSACTIONS in Remix and you need MetaMask to deploy this way), the error disappeared.

I added the following function to the contract:

```
  function blockValue() view public returns (uint256) {
      return uint256(blockhash(block.number - 1));
  }
```

and it was still throwing the error when calling `blockValue` instead of `flip`. So I think the reason is that the simulation of blocks in JavaScript VM isn't realistic enough for `blockhash` to work properly.

Answer to secondary question: I passed `true` and it incremented `consecutiveWins`, so `true` and `false` should be correct.

Comment: Encountered and figured the same: blockhash(block.number - 1) seems to be the issue, probably because there is no previous block in a fresh network.

Comment: Yes, blockhash() does not work properly on the remix testnet